# Who killed the Famous Historian?

Tags: arthurian, monty-python, monty-python-holy-grail

At the end of *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*,

> King Arthur and his men are arrested for the murder of Frank the Famous Historian.

[Earlier in the film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-HjOeCvm2I), we see Frank murdered by an unknown knight dressed similarly to the Knights of the Round Table. However, the knight who kills him rides a real horse, while King Arthur and his men merely have coconuts.

Did King Arthur or one of his men kill Frank, or were they framed?

Comment: The script just says "A knight".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Singing Camelot Knight #4

[Who was played by John Cleese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python_and_the_Holy_Grail#Cast) (who also played Sir Lancelot the Brave).

You can see yellow and silver in this frame:

[image]

This knight is also wearing yellow and silver, and the crest is conceivably the same:

[image]

And in case you are not quite sure who's face that is, here is John Cleese wear the same pattern and crest:

[image]

So yes, a knight from Camelot killed Frank the Historian.<sup>*1*</sup>

---

<sub>*1: Assuming there is any sort of continuity with costumes in this movie.*</sub>

Comment: He sure is displaying his "footwork impecc-able" in that last photo...